# \newtheoremstyle above space does nothing in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, floats, theorems

I would like to change the space above and below a `\newtheorem` in beamer. I tried to use `\newtheoremstyle`, but nothing happens. Here is an example showing above space set to 3000pt which has no effect at all. How do I best achieve what I want?

```
\documentclass[12pt, aspectratio=169, noamssymb]{beamer} 
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheoremstyle{newstyle}
  {3000pt}   % ABOVESPACE
  {3000pt}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\theoremstyle{newstyle}
\newtheorem{teorem}{\normalsize \color{white} \bfseries Teorem}
\newtheorem{korollar}{\normalsize \color{white} \bfseries Korollar}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{teorem}[Skjæringssetningen]
La $X$ være et koblet og $Y$ er en ordnet mengde i ordentopologien. La $f: X \to Y$ være kontinuerlig. Hvis $a,b \in X$ og $r \in Y$ slik at $f(a) <r < f(b)$, da eksisterer $c \in X$ slik at $f(c) = r$. 
\end{teorem}
\begin{korollar}
Anta at $f:[a,b] \to R$ er kontinuerlig og $r \in R$ slik at $f(a) <r < f(b)$, da eksisterer $c \in [a,b]$ slik at $f(c) = r$. 
\end{korollar}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beamer need not care about that. If you want to design a new style, play with beamer templates. In this case, you probably need to access to `theorem begin`.

Answer (score 2):

Beamer treats all the `newtheorem`s like its own theorem environment, so if you want to adjust the spacing simply add it to the relevant beamer templates:

```
\documentclass[12pt, aspectratio=169, noamssymb]{beamer} 
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheoremstyle{newstyle}
{3000pt}   % ABOVESPACE
{3000pt}   % BELOWSPACE
{\normalfont}  % BODYFONT
{0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
{\bfseries} % HEADFONT
{.}         % HEADPUNCT
{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
{}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\theoremstyle{newstyle}
\newtheorem{teorem}{\normalsize \color{white} \bfseries Teorem}
\newtheorem{korollar}{\normalsize \color{white} \bfseries Korollar}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\addtobeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%
    \vspace{0.5cm}
}

\addtobeamertemplate{theorem end}{%
    \vspace{0,5cm}
}


\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{teorem}[Skjæringssetningen]
            La $X$ være et koblet og $Y$ er en ordnet mengde i ordentopologien. La $f: X \to Y$ være kontinuerlig. Hvis $a,b \in X$ og $r \in Y$ slik at $f(a) <r < f(b)$, da eksisterer $c \in X$ slik at $f(c) = r$. 
        \end{teorem}
        \begin{korollar}
            Anta at $f:[a,b] \to R$ er kontinuerlig og $r \in R$ slik at $f(a) <r < f(b)$, da eksisterer $c \in [a,b]$ slik at $f(c) = r$. 
        \end{korollar}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]